# Выбрать наиболее приближенную дату из массива

Tags: php, массивы

Есть 2 массива с датами, которые заполняются из БД:

```
 while($row2 = $infvega_date->fetch_assoc()){
     $date1 = $row2['new_date'];
     $timestamp1 = strtotime($date1);
     $timestamp1 = date("Y.m.d",$timestamp1);
     $arr1[] = $timestamp1;
 }

 while($row1 = $arcvega_date->fetch_assoc()){
     $date2 = $row1['num_date'];
     $timestamp2 = strtotime($date2);
     $timestamp2 = date("Y.m.d",$timestamp2);
     $arr2[] = $timestamp2;
 }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как для каждой даты из массива 1 выбрать наиболее приближенную дату из массива 2?

UPD.

Возьмем например 2 массива:

```
 $arr1 = array('2018.03.29','2018.03.29','2018.03.29',
               '2018.04.17','2018.04.17');
 $arr2 = array('2018.02.28','2018.03.30','2018.04.29','2018.05.10');

 foreach($arr1 as $id1 => $value1){
     foreach($arr2 as $id2 => $value2){
         if($value2 <= $value1){
             $result[] = $id1.")".$value1 . "=>" . $id2.")". $value2;

         }
     }
 }
```

В массиве $result будет занесено следующее:

```
 0 => 2018.03.29=>2018.02.28
 1 => 2018.03.29=>2018.02.28
 2 => 2018.03.29=>2018.02.28
 3 => 2018.04.17=>2018.02.28
 4 => 2018.04.17=>2018.03.30
 5 => 2018.04.17=>2018.02.28
 6 => 2018.04.17=>2018.03.30
```

В принципе сравнивает правильно, но как отбросить ненужное и оставить наиболее приближенное значение? Например дата "2018-03-30" (индекс 4 и 6) наиболее приближена к "2018-04-17", значит дату "2018-02-28" (индекс 3 и 5) нужно отбросить

Comment: для начала надо определиться, как узнать например, число дней между двумя датами. Вам же поэтому критерию надо искать минимум?

Comment: Мне нужно искать не минимум, а наиболее приближенную дату. Скажем если в первом массиве есть дата "2018-05-10", а во втором массиве даты "2018-04-12", "2018-05-02", "2018-05-11", то должна выбраться дата НЕ ПРЕВЫШАЮЩАЯ дату из первого массива, т.е. "2018-05-11".

Comment: минимум разности и приближенная это одно и то же. А вот про то, что надо отсеять даты в будущем вы упомянуть в вопросе забыли.

Answer (score 1):

Допустим у нас есть массив дат

```
    $dates = [ '0'=> "2018-02-10",
               '1'=> "2018-02-12",
               '2'=> "2018-02-15",
               '3'=> "2018-01-18",
               '4'=> "2018-01-20"];

    function find_closest_date($array, $date){
        foreach($array as $day){
            $interval[] = abs(strtotime($date) - strtotime($day));
        }
        asort($interval);
        $closest = key($interval);

        print_r ($array[$closest]);
    }

   find_closest_date($dates, "2018-01-19");
```

Comment: сортировать массив для нахождения минимального значения - не самое эффективное  решение. и зачем $date каждую итерацию парсить?

Comment: предложите свой вариант в ответах, с удовольствием посмотрим